# Accessing only one of the return values from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

How do I only access one of the values:

my code:

```
def test():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = 6

    return a, b, c 

a = test().a  # only want "a" from the function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a dictionary instead:

```
def test():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = 6

    return {"a":a, "b":b, "c":c}

print(test()["a"])

4
```

If you want to stick with your current approach, then the best you might be able to do would be to just print the first element from the tuple returned:

```
print(test()[0])
```

But this of course means that the caller would have to know that `a` happens to coincide with the first value.

Comment: I guess we can use `locals()` instead of creating the dictionary :)

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the other values by using a placeholder `_`

```
def test():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = 6

    return a, b,  c

#Ignore b and c
a, _, _ = test()
print(a)
#4
```

Or you could return a dictionary of values and access `a` from the dictionary

```
def test():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = 6

    return locals()

print(test()['a'])
#4
```

Or you could just use indexing to find the first element of the returned tuple, given you know `a` is the first element, as per [Tim's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55984318/8591431) above

```
def test():
    a = 4
    b = 5
    c = 6

    return a, b, c

print(test()[0])
#a
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `test()` returns a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) so in order to access `a` you would have to use the following code:

```
a = test()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

```
a, b, c = test() # ignore b and c

a, *_ = test() # ignore _ which captures b and c

a = test()[0]

a = test()
a[0] # which is equal to the 'a' inside the test function.
```